# How to store JSON object in database

Tags: mysql, spring, mongodb, postgresql, hibernate

I have json objects data collection provided in JSON string. I need to store it in database. Our second team will use this data from database and they need most of this json object data fields be indexable and searchable. Without this, the data will be hard to use, as its amount could be large (think about million records+ per year)  Now they use SQL stored procedures mostly. I have doubts what storage should I use.

1.

The most straightforward is to create in SQL database table with columns:

- id
- json_id
- json_value

Than I can link this table data with objects stored in SQL database tables and map with Spring Repository and Hibernate. This will need to convert every json object to Java objects collection to store.

2.

Second approach is MongoDB. I know it works fine with search and allow indexing on JSON object fields. It is good described how to insert read and search data. Though I not used any mapping tool yet with it. Also this solution absolutely new to other team.

3.

MySQL and PostgreSQL. I know both database engines have JSON data type, but I not see any description about how easy to implement search and indexing with them. The advantage here is Hibernate mapping possible and I see few example on the web.

The first and second approaches more or less clear, but what about MySQL or PostgreSQL JSON data format?

Comment: JSON is used for storing data it self. JSON and Database are both a way of storing data. Therefore, I don't recommend storing JSON directly but extracting it and then saving the data in database.

Comment: Also, please show what the JSON looks like, so I can give a suitable answer for your need.

Comment: Why not consider MongoDB? It's literally a document-based database and its BSON format it's very similar to JSON. Maybe it's better suited for your application

Comment: @WebGuy You should think about JSON object of any structure. I should be able to save any valid json object. MongoDB, MySQL, PostgreSQL all provide JSON format data for storage.

Comment: @Sergio La Rosa Please take a look at option 2 - it is exactly about MongoDB

Comment: MySQL should be good enough for the requirements mentioned above and you can increase the indexing performance by using queries properly. Here is a nice guide, to help you get started: http://odetocode.com/articles/237.aspx

Comment: @WebGuy Do you mean approach listed in 1, 3 or something different? I need to search and index on JSON object properties, but not on raw JSON string. Hope explained clear enough...

Comment: @Pavlo oh, sorry, my bad. Didn't noticed!

Comment: I would recommend approach 3. see this link. https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/

Comment: @Pavlo you could also create a small proof-of-concept code using all 3 approaches to determine which approach you & your team will be most comfortable with. It's impossible to determine your exact needs since we don't know your expertise and your process, and any answer we give would be "best" from our own point of view, not yours. If this is going to be a long-term project, the time you spent doing POC code will be time well spent.